# Jinja2 Tempates Subdirectory

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

I'm attempting to organize Jinja2 templates in a way that makes them more manageable. For example, I have a set of team-oriented pages, and a set of prototypes, so my dir structure is:

app > templates > foo_dir > bar.html

In my script that's rendering the templates, I have the following:

```
templates_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
JINJA_PAGES = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(templates_dir),
  extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
  autoescape=True)


class Page(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  category = None
  template = category + None
  url = None

  def get(self):
    template = JINJA_PAGES.get_template(self.template)
    rendered = template.render(self.TemplateArgs())
    self.response.write(rendered)

  def TemplateArgs(self):
    return {}


class FooPage(Page):

  category = 'page_category'
  template = templates_subdir + 'template_name'
  url = '/foo'
```

How do I access the templates in subdirectories in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [FileSystemLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.FileSystemLoader), it looks like you can pass a list of directories to be searched (in order).  i.e.:

```
templates_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
foo_dir = os.path.join(templates_dir, 'foo_dir')
JINJA_PAGES = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader([templates_dir, foo_dir]),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

now `JINJA_PAGES.get_template` will look first in `templates_dir` for the requested template.  If that template isn't found, it will next look in `foo_dir`.

Comment: Indeed it can. You can extend templates from one dir to those in another without any args.

Comment: Well then, that's very good to know.  I would have guessed that would work alright, but it's good that you've verified it.  Thanks!